# How to make layout scrollable both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I know how to make a layout scrollable vertically, by placing it into a ScrollView. But how can I make it side-scrollable as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ScrollView` and `HorizontalScrollView` are layout container for a `view hierarchy` that can be scrolled vertically or horizontally by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A `ScrollView/HorizontalScrollView` is a `FrameLayout`, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

Here is xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inside 1st HorizontalScrollView" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button A1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button A2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button A3" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button A4" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button A5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inside 2nd HorizontalScrollView" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B3" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B4" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B5" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button B6" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inside ScrollView" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button C" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button D" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button E" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button F" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button G" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button H" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button I" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

for more detail visit this : http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/01/scrollview-and-horizontalscrollview.html

## Update :

use this xml to scroll `vertical` as well as `horizontal`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   
            

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, didn't know horizontal scroll view exists. Just one quick question: How to make layout to be scrollable and horizontally scrollable at the same time? Would it work if I put HorizontalScrollView as the child of the ScrollView and then make the original layout the child of HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: @Leonz put `HorizontalScrollView` inside `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers my question completely.

Comment: Solved my problem too, thanks, however is there a way to hide vertical sidebars?

Comment: @Sykox Change android:scrollbars="vertical" to android:scrollbars="none"